# How to make on prem AD users to use Azure AD's primary custom domain as UPN suffix for cloud services

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

My client wants to use their Azure AD public domain as UPN suffix for their synced on prem usernames. 
Right now users are synced with their on prem UPN suffix
For e.g. they have subdomain.domain.com as primary custom domain for Azure AD and corp.local.com as verified custom domain that matches their local AD domain

I had setup AD Connect to sync on prem AD users to Azure AD. 
Initially they wanted to authenticate using on prem login so I had enabled and setup Pass Through Authentication.

Added TXT record to public domain for local domain name.
So now they have 3 custom domains
1. subdomain.domain.com - Verified - Public
2. Default onmicrosoft domain - Enabled
3. corp.local.com - Verified

Due to this they have all the users ported to AAD as @corp.local.com

Now they want users to be authenticated using Public Domain UPN suffix so I change AD connect 'Azure sign in' step to Password Hash Sync (disabled PTA, removed agent from Domain Controller) but it did not work

I tried to use mail parameter (email address matches with public domain name) as UPN via custom installation of AD Connect but it took first part of email address and attached default onmicrosoft UPN suffix when users ported to Azure AD

Please help me how to achieve this?

1. If I delete verified local domain name from Azure AD Custom Domain and resync then will users port to Azure AD with @subdomain.domain.com (as this is my primary domain) or will it port to @onmicrosoft.com?
2. If I set alternate UPN suffix for On prem AD then will it create new user ID with new suffix for existing user? or will it modify existing user names? Or do I have to run some script to change UPN suffix for existing users?
   And if client is not willing to set Alternate UPN suffix for on prem users then what is the other option

Thanks in advance

[Edit]
Based on what I have read so far there are two ways:
1. Add alternate UPN suffix to local domain and run power shell script and change all user's suffix to added alternate suffix. They Sync will port these users with proper UPN Suffix
- Question is, will this affect any existing local/intranet app authentication?

2. Customized Synchronization Rule in AD Connect

   - Did not get much material on this. Would be really helpful if anyone can point me to right directions

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I can answer question 1, but I can answer question 2.

Adding an alternate UPN suffix is optional. AD doesn't actually enforce those suffixes. While AD Users and Computers gives you a drop-down of the suffixes, you can actually set the UPN suffix to anything if you modify the `userPrincipalName` attribute directly (in the Attribute Editor or via code).

Here at my work, we have a hybrid environment (on-prem synced with Azure AD) and we *must* use a specific UPN suffix for Azure AD / Office 365 to work properly, but that suffix was never added in the list of alternate UPN suffixes. (I don't know why to be honest)

But there is nothing that will change the UPN suffix on accounts automatically. You will have to run a script to modify them.

*Update:* To address your new question 1: To reiterate, adding the alternate UPN suffix is optional. You don't *have to* do that before actually changing the UPN suffixes. But it does make sense to.

About affecting any local/intranet apps: Applications that use Windows authentication will continue to work in almost all cases. Our users were told to log into Windows using their new UPN (which now matches their email address) at least once (I don't exactly know why) instead of using the old DOMAIN\username format. However Windows still identified them as the same account, so didn't try to make them a new Windows profile or anything like that.

The only problem we had was with BMC Remedy. It's a Java application that does use Windows Authentication (behind Tomcat). The authentication itself still worked, but it uses the Kerberos token to read the username and then looks up the account details via LDAP. The problem there is that the Kerberos token always uses the `sAMAccountName@domainDNS`, which does not necessarily match the `userPrincipalName` in AD (it didn't anymore in our case). Our solution to that was to populate an unused attribute with the `sAMAccountName@domainDNS` on all of our accounts and have Remedy search for the account using that attribute.

But you may not have that problem. The best thing to do is switch over a couple accounts and test.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What do you mean by Hybrid environment? Do you know how On prem is synced with Azure AD? Password Hash or Pass through authentication?

Comment: Actually this is almost similar scenario I am facing. We need to use AAD specific public domain as UPN suffix for users that were synced from On prem AD. So any information about your setup would help me. When On prem users synced to Azure AD, what is their UPN suffix?Thanks

Comment: I'm not directly involved with how the sync is setup, but I was told that our on-prem does the authentication, so I think that means pass-through. The "User name" that shows up in the Azure AD portal is the UPN from on-prem. We only have a one-way sync (on-prem syncs to the cloud, but not the other way)

Comment: Thanks Ganriel but PTA is not useful in this scenario.

Comment: That's fine, although the type of authentication you're using may not have any effect on the need to change the UPN suffix. I saw the update to your question, so I've added some more details to my answer, based on our experience.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Solution you suggested for BMC remedy will be helpful if we run into that issue.